# Can't save entity to databse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

When I try to save user object to db, i get

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException
        for SQL [insert into users (created_at, email, first_name, last_name, password, role_, status) values (?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, &#39;User&#39;, ?)]; SQL state [S1009]; error code [0]; could not insert:
        [com.hramyko.finalapp.entity.User]; nested exception
```

But when i use method save to update existing user all works correctly

My User entity

```
   package com.hramyko.finalapp.entity;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "role_")
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected int id;
    protected String email;
    protected String password;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    protected String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    protected String lastName;
    @DateTimeFormat
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    protected Date createdAt;
    @Column(name = "role_")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    protected Role role;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    protected Status status;

}
```

My service method

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        userValidator.validate(user);
        user = userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
```

My repository

```
package com.hramyko.finalapp.repository;

import com.hramyko.finalapp.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    User findUserByEmail(String email);
}
```

Did anyone have a similar problem? I've tried everything already.

Comment: what does the rest of the stacktrace say?

Comment: The stack trace you've posted ends at "nested exception" but that nested exception is most likely the relevant portion. Most likely you're getting some constraint validation that the validator didn't catch.

Comment: @Stultuske sorry didnt captured  nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not
  insert: [com.hramyko.finalapp.entity.User]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inheritance is funky. You have annotations from conflicting inheritance strategies:

- Joined table: `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`
- Single table with discriminator `@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "role_")`

See [Hibernate Inheritance Mapping](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance)

On top of that, you are trying to insert the instance from the root of the inheritance hierarchy: `User` while you should be inserting a subclass instead.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, i just tested this @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "role_")